# Authenticating a cURL request in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I am trying to work with Blizzard's API to retrieve data from their JSON services (authentication documentation - http://blizzard.github.io/api-wow-docs/#features/authentication). I currently have the following function that looks after my cURL requests:

```
function get_json($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I have looked into the authentication requirements and have obtained a public and private key. They provide this to explain the process:

> ```
>   UrlPath = <HTTP-Request-URI, from the port to the query string>
>   StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" + Date + "\n" + UrlPath + "\n";
>   Signature = Base64( HMAC-SHA1( UTF-8-Encoding-Of( PrivateKey ), StringToSign ) );
>   Header = "Authorization: BNET" + " " + PublicKey + ":" + Signature;
> ```

I have tried researching PHP handling cURL authentication but it just confused me more. My question is how do I include the authentication in the get_json function?

Comment: I found this - and am attempting to work out where it fits in.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password)));

Answer (score 2):

Found this code by the guys at http://sourceforge.net/projects/wowarmoryapi/

```
private function getByKeys($url,$region){
    $pubkey = $GLOBALS['wowarmory']['keys']['public'];
    $privkey = $GLOBALS['wowarmory']['keys']['private'];
    $url = preg_replace('/^http/', 'https', $url);
    $date = date('D, d M Y G:i:s T',time());
    $stringtosign = "GET\n".$date."\n".$url."\n";
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $stringtosign, $privkey,true));
    $header = array("Host: ".$this->regions[$region],"Date: ". $date,"\nAuthorization: BNET ". $pubkey.":". base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', "GET\n".$date."\n".$url."\n", $privkey, true))."\n");

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
    return $response;
}
```